# How can I suspend a member of a Telegram group if they send too many messages?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

We have a Telegram group. Some users overuse it by sending many messages or long messages. We want to limit people to certain amount of messages in a specific period. If someone exceed this limit, we like to ban it temporary until the period passes.

Is it possible via a robot? Is there a robot for this purpose? if not, how can I write it and where can I host it so that I can use it?

Comment: Try searching? Explaining how to write a bot, how to count messages and how to ban users would not fit in one answer. Start at https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot for example and try building something, then come back if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [restrictChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#restrictchatmember) method for Supergroup.

Comment: Thank you, it is a useful method.